# What is a Factor in R and why do we need it

Tags: r, statistics, data-science

I am new to R language and am not able to understand the need to use/have Factors in R and its killing me. I read a lot but still have not found the satisfactory answer. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is a way to associate numbers to different values of a categorical variable.
Let's say you have a vector of genders, and you wish to introduce it to some model (lm for example). Then you need to code the values (0/1 perhaps). Here you will use `factor` on the vector of genders